# R uploading files with a function

Tags: r

I usually use the upload button to upload a file, bui i would like to do it with a function. So i need a function to upload a binary file from my desktop to a remote Rstudio. The path is always the same. The size of the file is 70Mb. Which is the easiest way?

Comment: What protocol are you using? Is the button on a website? Which one?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aTv2gHYhreM i usually use this procedure

Answer (score 1):

We can use base R's `file.copy`.

E.g.

```
file.copy(from="path_to_local_source_file", to="path_to_RStudioServer_destination_file")
```

## Edit:

For `file.copy` to work, the (local) source directory needs to be mounted on the (probably Ubuntu) system RStudioServer is running on. We can use PAM session on 'RStudioServer Pro'... not sure about non 'Pro' version..

Comment: I have tried this: `file.copy(from="C:/Users/cristina/source/repos/GRAL3/Source/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/data.R",to="/home/stefano23/GRAL",overwrite  =TRUE)`, but it doen't work. `No such file or directory`

Comment: hm, that's strange. I'd double check that the paths are valid (e.g. with `file.exists("C:/Users/cristina/source/repos/GRAL3/Source/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/data.R")`  and `dir.exists("/home/stefano23/GRAL")` etc. and make sure that you have the rights to write to the 'dest' directory. Without further details it's going to be difficult to troubleshoot that...

Comment: `file.exists("C:/Users/cristina/source/repos/GRAL3/Source/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/data.R")`  is `FALSE` when i work with client of a remote server. But when i work with a local app of Rstudio (without connection with that server), it's `TRUE`.

Comment: Ok, looks like you didn't mount the drive/folder in RStudioServer... That's why you can't access the file!